# display image in a php function link

Tags: php, function, hyperlink

i have a question in regards to the following.

i have the function

```
    function print_link($link_num)
{
    global $error_str;
    if($link_num) {
    $error_str .= "<a href=\"page.php?toloc=$link_num\"><img src='img/Move.png'/>$link_num</a>"
    ;


    }
```

which displays an image next to a number according to `$link_num`

i have created a folder with images assigned to this number (`$link_num`).

im trying to display an image without having the need to display `$link_num` and the image.

so far ive tried

```
$error_str .= "<a href=\"page.php?toloc=$link_num\"><img src="img/'.$link_num.'.png" />";
```

but i get an unexpected T_STRING error.

my knowlege of php is not so good, is there a way i can link the image directly from my folder according to `$link_num`?

i hope ive been clear.
thank you for reading.

Comment: poor coding practices here :(

Comment: that's an awful error handler there

Comment: You have some quote issues in your second piece of code. `'<a href="page.php?toloc=' . $link_num . '"><img src="img/'.$link_num.'.png" />'`

Comment: I wonder if this error handler will produce an error...? Irony?

Comment: :( im still learning. thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing your " and ' within the code. The first " in the img tag is not being escaped properly and hence caused a parse error on the page try:

```
$error_str .= "<a href=\"page.php?toloc=$link_num\"><img src=\"img/".$link_num.".png\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the dot (.) in ".png":

```
$error_str .= "<a href=\"page.php?toloc=$link_num\"><img src="img/'.$link_num.'\.png" />";
```

But to make it more clear use only one type of ":

```
$error_str .= '<a href="page.php?toloc='.$link_num.'"><img src="img/'.$link_num.'.png" />';
```

Comment: You never have to escape the dot in a string (apart from regex). It is a quotation mark issue.

Comment: escape the dot? and what about .php in the link?

Comment: absolutely the escape in the dot. thank you gentlemen, and/or ladies